# Cosigner is deceased, is spouse automatically put on mortgage

Tags: mortgage, death

My father passed away in 2014. My original bank sold my mortgage to another bank. The new bank put my mother's name on my mortgage statement. What does that mean for both of us? I did fill out a quit claim deed at the courthouse.  Not sure what that did to this situation if anything.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make the scenario clearer? Here's what I think is happening. Your father was a cosigner to *your* mortgage. Was he also on the deed? After his death, your mortgage company added your mother's name to the mortgage statement. What exactly did the quit-claim deed do?

Comment: Who is included in "Both of us" and are you saying you co-signed the original loan with your dad? The question is confusing.

Comment: Who bought and owns the house? Who signed (and co-signed) the mortgage? When and why did you fill out a quitclaim deed?

Comment: Also, where in the world are you? This will likely depend on local laws in your country. Please [edit] your question to include a country tag

Comment: You have a good question, but it lacks important details. Please edit and it will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

What controls this is who is named on the note that is secured by the mortgage.  The fact that your mortgage was sold doesn't matter at all and nobody can be added as a debtor without their permission.

Unless you were an owner of the property, the quit claim deed means nothing.  What you are saying by that is that "I don't know who owns this but it's not me".  If, however, you signed the note, that will not relieve you of responsibility to pay.